# Interface management eclipse

Tags: java, swing, frame

I al reading a code that I did not create and I have some trouble to understand how it is working and especially how action event ( like a click) are managed ?

So far I am undertanding that it creates a the first window will all buttons and boxes and the main end with a setVisible(true); and my window appears.

Then is ask my some file locations and I click on a button to go to the second window.

What I would like to understand it is how in java we managed this click event for the second action ? I mean I understand the use of button addActionListener the first time but my understanding ends with the second event (=I click on the button and it brings me to the second window and do the calculation) i.e. where/ how in the code this is handle and goes a scond time to the functions.

Knowing that at the end of the main I have some functions starting with

InterfaceDynamics.cardSwitch() and this function managed all events that can occur
public static void cardSwitch(final String _buttonKey, final String _Key, final JPanel _cardPanel,

Another related question (I guess related) it is the use of

```
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new Main();
```

which I really do not undertand (even if I already google it).

Sorry if I am not clear and for my bad understanding of java and window, Swing, Frame management and really thanks for any help.

Regards

Comment: Have you looked into what the first ActionListener does? I am assuming it sets up the second window.

Comment: Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for info about your `invokeLater` method. For the window that comes up, the handling will be in the `actionPerformed` method most likely since you're using a `JButton`. Look for that method and that will probably clarify doubts for you.